# Nested linear layout with 40+ buttons crashing Android test device

Tags: android

Using Android Studio, I'm creating a 10x10 grid for a game using nested linear layouts and ImageButtons for each row.  I'm testing on an emulator and an Android device.  The grid shows up fine in the emulator, but crashes on the device.

As part of my troubleshooting, I decided to implement one row at a time to see the point of the crash.  At 5 rows, the device will install but not display the grid (screen goes black and then back to desktop) and the LogCat goes crazy.  I don't see anything in the LogCat indicating the cause, however.  I haven't been able to find anything online that might explain this.  I am aware that nesting weights may cause issues, but I don't know any other way to get the layout I want--and I found that solution here on SO.

My XML file is below.  At present, I haven't done anything with the auto-generated MainActivity.java file.  I'm just working on the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <!-- App Name -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <!-- End App Name -->

    <!-- Grid -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#06d7ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <!-- Row 0 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r0c9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Row 0 -->

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r1c9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Row 1 -->

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/r2c9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Row 2 -->

        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/row3">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c0"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c1"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c2"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c3"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c4"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c5"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c6"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c7"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c8"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r3c9"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Row 3 -->

        <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS -->
        <!-- Row 4 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/row4">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r4c9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ocean"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Row 4 -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End Grid -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/score"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="48sp"/>
    <!-- End Footer -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I made some graphical changes to the app (min API 14).  Now, the main activity has a few menu buttons and a 500kb jpg for the background.  When I click the button to launch the game activity with the 40+ buttons mentioned previously, the app crashes on my Android device (API 16).  It also crashes the emulator with the below error.  I can see that there is an out of memory error.  When I remove the background from the main activity, as expected, the app doesn’t crash the emulator when launching the game activity.  However, my device still crashes.  When I remove 10 buttons (30 remaining), the game activity launches on both the emulator and my device, but it takes a little while to transition on the device.  I’m not sure if generating the buttons dynamically will eliminate the OOM error.  I created the UI with XML simply because I am unable (or don’t know enough) to use all of the properties I need, such as weight, to ensure the buttons in my grid are proportioned correctly.  Conclusion: It’s likely an OOM error, but I’m not sure how to resolve it.

Here is part of the error (character limit) I get when the emulator crashes.  Game.java:13 is simply the call to `setContentView(R.layout.game)`:

```
***
07-10 15:19:52.103  18524-18524/com.android.battleships I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 07-10 15:19:52.103 18524:18524 D/skia     ]
    --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
07-10 15:19:52.103  18524-18524/com.android.battleships D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-10 15:19:52.103  18524-18524/com.android.battleships W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d13b20)
07-10 15:19:52.103  18524-18524/com.android.battleships E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.battleships, PID: 18524
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.battleships/com.android.battleships.Game}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
            ***
            at com.android.battleships.Game.onCreate(Game.java:13)
            ***
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            ***
            at com.android.battleships.Game.onCreate(Game.java:13)
            ***
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            ***
            at com.android.battleships.Game.onCreate(Game.java:13)
            ***
```

Comment: You would need to post the stacktrace from the crash

Comment: I would suggest you create this layout with code vs having a giant layout file.

Comment: If you're using a "Grid" then use `GridLayout`. Easier to manager, and no nesting.

Comment: Try using a TableLayout instead.

Comment: I made some changes to my app and posted new details above. @codeMagic, I included part of the stacktrace.

Comment: @Jared, I would definitely prefer to do this programmatically, but I can't get the layout to place the buttons proportionally. Unless I'm missing something, everything I've found on using weights in layouts doesn't work for me and I need to have a perfect button grid.

Comment: Why not just use GridlayoutManager + RecyclerView.

Comment: I'm new to Android development, so not familiar with RecyclerView.  I can certainly look into it.  In the meantime, I need to resolve the out of memory error.  No one has told me yet if nested layout is the problem or graphics or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! I was on the right track with the graphics causing the out of memory error. The files were too large, especially with the PNGs. I resized everything and converted to JPG. Also created multiple resolutions for the background. Everything loads and loads quickly. Now I need to work on creating the buttons programmatically.